# maven-surefire-report-plugin is not called during building

Tags: maven-surefire-plugin

I defined the following pom.xml file for generating of reports during an integration testing.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
                <configuration>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
</plugin>
```

If the mvn verify is executed,there are no reports created. I have to use mvn surefire-report:report  for generating.
The above mentioned pom.xml file is parent for two children to be clear.
Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the above solution works just only if it is defined in child pom.xml file. It does not work in parent one. Is it bug or what is going on? I spent several hours when I got it!